# Dynamic reload of src

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to setting of src dynamically in my code, But it does n't work.

I dont know where I am missing. Please find the fiddle link below

```
function test() {
    alert("Inside function");
    var img = document.getElementById('test');
    img.src = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/prod-appreiz/team/5.png";
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kishore_Indraganti/boa20h9o/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the function is within scope, which means setting up the fiddle correctly with *"no wrap-in body"*.

Also, use a different function name as `window.test` is already defined, it's the element you're trying to get because ID's are written to the `window`, and using the same name for the function overwrites the reference to the ID `test`

```
function _test(){
    alert("Inside function");
    var img = document.getElementById('test');
    img.src = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/prod-appreiz/team/5.png";
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/boa20h9o/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).delegate(':file', 'change', function() {
    alert("Inside function");
    var img = document.getElementById('test');
    img.src = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/prod-appreiz/team/5.png";
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZH4QD/138/)